# What is the best way to embed many videos and pan/zoom to navigate the page?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, html5-video

I am trying to put on a page couple of videos(mp4) on a html5 canvas, then implement pan & zoom with JS as a navigation for them. The problem is that it becomes heavy to navigate quite soon. So I decided to use simple screenshot of the video and actually embed img tag instead of video, and then pan. Did you come across another solution, which would be helpful?

Comment: Why would you use a canvas?
Can't you just have a big container (400% width and 400% tall, for example), position the videos absolutely in it and then make it draggable?

Comment: Yes maybe you are right, but even then the "performance" problem would stay, wouldn't it?

Comment: I don't think so, if you use the html5 video tag you can specify a placeholder image. For the dragging part you can use css3 transforms which can be hardware accelerated.
I just had to make a big draggable and zoomable site and ended up using leafletjs ( http://leafletjs.com/ ) which is really nice, easy and fast and handles the whole panning zooming thing.

Comment: So is leafletjs usable without a map, or your project also involved a map?

Comment: You can use whatever image you want as a background. Or do you have no background at all?